# Desligar o computador quando um determinado programa fechar

Tags: script, bat

Estou transformando um CPU antiga em um servidor de Minecraft. Ao ligar o computador, consigo via script fazer com que ele abra o servidor (iniciando um arquivo -jar), entretanto, gostaria de fazê-lo desligar assim que o programa -jar se encerrasse.

O script que tenho é esse, que só faz com que ele seja aberto

```
@ECHO OFF
start java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
pause
```

Poderiam me indicar o código que faz o computador desligar assim que o "minecraft_server.jar" for fechado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para desligar o computador, você pode utilizar o comando `shutdown` passando como parâmetro `/s`, da seguinte forma:

```
shutdown /s
```

Como você deseja desligar somente depois do programa encerrar, você pode criar o seu script utilizando o parâmetro `/wait` do comando `start`, com isso o script aguarda o encerramento do programa executado pelo `start`.

---

Seu script ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
@ECHO OFF
start /wait java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
shutdown /s
```

Assim que o `java` for encerrado, vai cair no comando de desligamento.

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start